FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads.png' in Python
Everything was going smoothly until I tried to use PIL, I have been stuck on this for a few days, so if you can help, it will be very good.
import PIL
from PIL import Image
fp = Image.open(r"C:\Users\User\Downloads.png")
im.show()

I have also tried different ways like:
import PIL
from PIL import Image
file_name="C:\Users\User\Downloads.png"
fp = Image.open(file_name,"r")
im.show()

Which has shown:
none
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I have also changed it to:
file_name="C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads.png"

But it shows another error:
But it mostly shows:
none
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\pythonProject\.venv\image 0.1.py", line 4, in <module>
    fp = Image.open(file_name,"r")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3431, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads.png'

I am on Windows and use PyCharm; if you can help, it will be amazing.

First things I am noticing is double import statements of the same library, which is unnecessary. Secondly, try using forward slashes (/) instead and let me know how it goes.

You don't need import PIL.

@Shreyas Salankimatt  Thank you for you help and using forward slashes did not work however , changing it to the path and adding 2 slashes did work - "C:\Users\User\Downloads\ybearoutput-300x225.png"

@MarkSetchell Thank you , i don't think removing it made a difference but it did make the code shorter

I was able to download PIL (see this link: [Pillow Documentation])1 and run the code successfully using a png file in my downloads folder
Here is the code:
import PIL
from PIL import Image
fp = Image.open('/Users/xxx/Downloads/Screenshot 2024-07-13 at 5.48.46 PM.png') # please replace 'xxx' with your path name
fp.show()  # I changed 'im' to 'fp' since 'im' is not defined

Here is the image I got
Feel free to follow up if it's still not working.
Regarding system difference, I am using a Mac but have PC too. I can check that out for you too. A potentially useful trick to share regarding using PC: you can go to the folder with your png file of interest, pressing 'shift' button while right click. That way, you will see an option to copy the path of the file. Then you just need to paste it to your code (saving the typing work and also avoiding
chance of errors). Pay attention to r string and add it if needed. Hope this helps.

Ok thank you so much about the problems the code had , i referenced to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ , which was very useful .I also used the correct path and changed all of the slashes from \ to \
